# how to change array to variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have an array in Javascript and I want to change it into a variable. For example, if variable `array=["a", "b", "c"]` then I want variable `variable` to equal `"abc"` What's the fastest wat to do this? (My real array has almost 100 values)

Comment: I suggest [javascript's `join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: How would I write that out completely? I just tried `variable=join(array)`, but that doesn't work

Comment: @CPC: Maybe you want to *read* the docs that he linked to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I advise you to check out the [documentation of arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

The short answer is use `Array.prototype.join`, it takes a parameter which is the glue, the string between each elements of your array into a string.

**UPDATE** If you don't pass a parameter to `Array.prototype.join` the glue will be a comma

```
var array = ["a", "b", "c"];

console.log(array.join('')); // abc
// another example here
console.log(array.join('-')); // a-b-c
// and another one to show the default behaviour
console.log(array.join()); // a,b,c
```

Comment: @CPC: You are using a variable `word` that isn't defined.